# Power BI Web.Contents Timeout

Tags: powerbi, aws-api-gateway

The data returned from my web service is a bit large. I am experiencing Timeout error(it says after 3.0 seconds) on Power BI Desktop even though I already added Timeout before my Headers parameter below. Is there something wrong with the following?

I am not experiencing any Timeout issues if I delete my source to a few hundred rows.

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("url",
    [
        Timeout=#duration(0,0,30,0),
        Headers=[#"x-api-key"="somekey"]
    ]
    ))
```

Comment: Any chance this timeout happens after exactly 5 minutes? Because that's what I am getting

Comment: Not sure, I think it's less than that.